# Kivy language cannot reference id with python code

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I read a Kivy document to reference a widget like self.ids.widget_id.text = "".

In my code, I used the same code I read to change the label widget to data, which is received from the database. I see data from MySql like "MARVEL’S SPIDER-MAN 2," but the program is showing an error which use self.ids.product_name.text = str(fetch[1]). How can I fix this error.

**productlistview.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from globalstate import GlobalState
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import connect_db

Builder.load_file('productlistview.kv')

class ProductListViewMain(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        GlobalState.is_user_authenticated = True
        # Check user authentication status
        if not GlobalState.is_user_authenticated:
            # If not authenticated, go to the login screen
            self.manager.current = 'home'
            return
        
class SearchProduct(GridLayout):
    pass

class ProductList(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProductList, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.load_products()

    def load_products(self):
        # Fetch data from MySQL
        mydb = connect_db.db
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Product"
        cursor.execute(sql)
            
        fetch = cursor.fetchone()

        # Close the connection
        mydb.close()

        if fetch:
            print(fetch[1]) # MARVEL’S SPIDER-MAN 2
            self.ids.product_name.text = str(fetch[1]) # Error
            
            

class ProductListViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = ProductListViewMain()
        return self.root
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProductListViewApp().run()
```

**productlistview.kv**

```
<ProductListViewMain>:
    SearchProduct:
        ProductList:

<SearchProduct>:
    cols: 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.898039, 0.898039, 0.909804, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        
    RelativeLayout:

        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Search'
            font_size: 45
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            background_color: 0.952941, 0.952941, 0.952941, 1
            foreground_color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 70
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 850
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.85}

<ProductList>:
    cols: 5
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 350
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 250

    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            id: product_image
            allow_stretch: True
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: None
            height: 250
            width: 250
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: product_name
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint: (0.146341, 0.0956522)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: product_description
            text: 'Description'
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint: (0.146341, 0.0956522)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: product_price
            text: 'Price'
            font_family: 'Roboto'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            size_hint: (0.146341, 0.0956522)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: add_cart
            text: 'add to cart'
            size_hint: (0.243902, 0.182609)
            foreground_color: 0.482353, 0.552941, 0.576471, 1
            background_color: 0.811765, 0.847059, 0.862745, 1
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            on_press: root.test()
```

**Error**

```
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
MARVEL’S SPIDER-MAN 2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'product_name'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/productlistview.py", line 55, in <module>
     ProductListViewApp().run()
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/productlistview.py", line 51, in build
     self.root = ProductListViewMain()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 274, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 366, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 658, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/productlistview.py", line 29, in __init__
     self.load_products()
   File "/Users/fluke/Desktop/SEP410/Apps/productlistview.py", line 45, in load_products
     self.ids.product_name.text = str(fetch[1])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. Did you mean: '__setattr__'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ids` of a widget are assigned when the widget is built for display. You are basically trying to access the `ids` from the `__init__()` method (because of the direct call to `self.load_products()`) which is called before the `ids` have been assigned. A simple fix is to slightly delay the use of the `ids` by using `Clock.schedule_once()`:

```
class ProductList(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProductList, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # self.load_products()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.load_products)

    def load_products(self, *args):
```

Note the addition of `*args` to the `load_products()` signature.